# Long chapter name second (and further) line(s) indent in the table of contents (TOC) using Memoir class

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, memoir

I'm LaTeX newbe and trying to make a document with some requirements.
Searching for similiar issues here and through whole internet gave me no result.
The point is to remove the long chapter name second (third, fourth...) line indent within the TOC.

**What I do have now:**

[image]

**What I want to have:**

[image]

**Detailed explanation:**

[image]

**LaTeX code (MWE):**

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}  % Using memoir class is essential

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}  % Table of Contents depth up to 2nd level
\setrmarg{2.55em plus1fil}  % No hyphenation within the Table of Contents


\begin{document}
  \renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}  % Enable dots for Chapter instances within the Table of Contents

  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
  \newcommand{\acronymsname}{This is a long, really long name for acronyms list to (no-hyphenation) show how it looks within the Table of Long Contents}
  \newcommand{\introductionname}{Introduction}

  \tableofcontents
  
  \chapter*{\acronymsname}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\acronymsname}  
  \begin{itemize}
      \item[\(E\)] --- E-letter
      \item[\(j\)] --- j-letter
      \item[\(k\)] --- k-letter
  \end{itemize}
  
  \chapter*{\introductionname}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\introductionname}
      Introduction text.
  
  \chapter{First Chapter}
    First Chapter text.
    \section{Section One in the 1st Chapter}
      ...Some text...
      \subsection{Subsection N1 within 1.1}
        ...New text...
      \subsection{Subsection N2 within 1.1}
        ...Other text...        
    \section{Section Two in the 1st Chapter}
      ...More text...
  
  \chapter{Second Chapter --- This Chapter Name is Really Long Too as Well as Acronyms List so it May Take at Least Two Strings}
    Second Chapter text.
    \section{Section One in the 2nd Chapter}
      ...Some text...
    \section{Section Two in the 2nd Chapter}
      ...More text...
\end{document}
```

***P.S.***
This post is an improved duplicate of the following posts:
[...latex.org...](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=34737),
[...stackoverflow.com...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71127932/long-chapter-name-second-line-indent-in-the-toc)

There are some answers on these links which may be useful for you.
But these answers do not fully correspond to my requirements described here.

***Thank you!***

Comment: note that you can reduce this MWE quite a lot.

Comment: While this seems not to be your goal, I'd say for the others: short chapter names for TOC can be given with optional parameters – `\chapter[Short title][Short title again]{Long long looooooong title}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done if you are a bit sneaky. Basically we make two copies of the macro that is typesetting chapter entries in the TOC. We modify one of them and then add and use hooks in to the TOC data to change which formatting macro is used when.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}  % Using memoir class is essential

\setrmarg{2.55em plus1fil}  % No hyphenation within the Table of Contents

\setlength\cftchapterindent{0pt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\let\normal@l@chapapp\l@chapapp
\let\special@l@chapapp\l@chapapp

\patchcmd{\special@l@chapapp}{\advance\memRTLleftskip\@tempdima}{}{\typeout{patch
    ok}}{\typeout{patch failed}}


\cftinsertcode{toc-frontmatter}{\let\l@chapapp\special@l@chapapp}
\cftinsertcode{toc-mainmatter}{\let\l@chapapp\normal@l@chapapp}

\makeatother

%\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\longname}{This is a long, really long name for acronyms
  list to (no-hyphenation) show how it looks within the Table of Long
  Contents}

\begin{document}

\cftinserthook{toc}{toc-frontmatter}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{\longname}
  
\cftinserthook{toc}{toc-mainmatter}

  
\mainmatter

\chapter{\longname}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and helpful solution!
I'll put my final version of the answer which fully corresponds to my requirements

Comment: @d_buch if it solved your problem remember to accept the answer (the check icon)

Answer (score 0):

**@daleif**s answer covers almost all of my requirements.
But not all of them. So I'd like to post my own result which uses **@daleif**s solution as a basement. I've just added some code to fulfil all of the requirements. Probably it may be helpful for some people.
Comments within the code are included.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}  % Using memoir class is essential
\usepackage{etoolbox} % Make macro writing/modifying possible

\makeatletter
  \let\normal@l@chapapp\l@chapapp % Normal chapter instance in toc
  \let\special@l@chapapp\l@chapapp % Special (without indent) chapter instance in toc

  \patchcmd{\special@l@chapapp}{\advance\memRTLleftskip\@tempdima} % Remove indent for Special chapter instance in toc
  {}
  {\typeout{patch ok}}
  {\typeout{patch failed}}

  \cftinsertcode{toc-front-back-matter}{\let\l@chapapp\special@l@chapapp} % Hook switcing to Special (without indent) chapter instance in toc
  \cftinsertcode{toc-main-matter}{\let\l@chapapp\normal@l@chapapp} % Hook switcing to Normal (with indent) chapter instance in toc
\makeatother

\makeatletter % According to my requirements the page numeration should be arabic through all the document (frontmatter, mainmatter, backmatter). This code enables it
\def\pagenumbering#1{%
  \gdef\thepage{\csname @#1\endcsname \c@page}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\longname}{This is a long, really long name for acronyms list to (no-hyphenation) show how it looks within the Table of Long Contents}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}  % Enable dots for Chapter instances within the Table of Contents

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}  % Table of Contents depth up to 2nd level
\setrmarg{2.55em plus1fil}  % No hyphenation within the Table of Contents

\begin{document}
  \cftinserthook{toc}{toc-front-back-matter}  % Hook switcing to the Special (without indent) chapter instance in toc
  \frontmatter  % Declare a front part or the document with the Special chapter instance and without chapter numbering
  \pagenumbering{arabic} % Restart page numbering with Arabic

  \tableofcontents*

  \chapter{\longname}

   
  \cftinserthook{toc}{toc-main-matter}  % Hook switcing to the Normal (with indent) chapter instance in toc
  \mainmatter % Declare a main part or the document with the Special chapter instance and with chapter numbering

  \chapter{First Chapter}
    First Chapter text.
    \section{Section One in the 1st Chapter}
      ...Some text...
      \subsection{Subsection N1 within 1.1}
        ...New text...
      \subsection{Subsection N2 within 1.1}
        ...Other text...        
    \section{Section Two in the 1st Chapter}
      ...More text...
  
  \chapter{Second Chapter --- This Chapter Name is Really Long Too as Well as Acronyms List so it May Take at Least Two Strings}
    Second Chapter text.
    \section{Section One in the 2nd Chapter}
      ...Some text...
    \section{Section Two in the 2nd Chapter}
      ...More text...

  \cftinserthook{toc}{toc-front-back-matter}  % Hook switcing to the Special (without indent) chapter instance in toc
  \backmatter % Declare a back part or the document with the Special chapter instance and without chapter numbering

  \chapter{Last Chapter Long Name which may be a Conclusion or a List Of Appendixes}
\end{document}
```

[image: The final result screenshot]

***P.S.***
Another working solution is posted [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=34737) by **Bartman** *(Fri Feb 18, 2022 7:30 am)*.